# npm install on windows 10 gets stuck at fetchMetadata

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

I have node.js installed on my Windows 10 machine. Node version is 6.10.3 and npm version is 3.10.10. 
  When I run npm install, it gets stuck at 
"[ ..............] - fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri registry.npmjs.org/zone.js"
  Can someone please suggest what might be the solution for this? I have tried with both the Node Windows Binary Package (.zip) and the Node Windows Installer (.msi).
  I have been trying from my home network, so I believe proxy is not the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, try this commands: 'npm config delete proxy' and
'npm config delete registry' or run 'npm config edit' and check that all settings in default state

Comment: Hi Sergaros,
  The delete proxy and delete registry commands were not of any help. 

  I ran npm config edit to check that all settings are in default state.

Any other thing might be causing the issue?

Comment: Maybe try  **npm cache clear**   or **npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org"**

Comment: No luck. Still npm install is getting stuck. I guess I might have done some trivial mistake which is blocking things. But not able to figure out what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Clear npm cache using the below command and then install

*npm cache clean*

Answer (score 0):

Clear npm cache using the below command and then install

if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.